# SASS: How do I used these gridlover maps?

Tags: sass

I've been introduced to the [gridlover](https://www.gridlover.net/try) tool. It provides SASS variables like:

```
$scale0: (
  fontSize: 1em,
  line: 1.5em,
  autoLineCount: 1,
  autoLineHeight: 1.5em
);
```

But I can't figure out what all the values correspond to.

I understand that I can use each one using `map-get`. `fontSize` is obviously used to set `font-size` and `line` looks like `line-height`.

```
.some-class {
  font-size: map-get($scale0, fontSize);
  line-height: map-get($scale0, line);
}
```

But what are `autoLineCount` and `autoLineHeight`? Are these SASS keywords? What am I suppose to do with them?

Comment: I dont know. But `line * autoLineCount = autoLineHeight`. Maybe can be used for scaling of spacing like margins and paddings?

Comment: [Twitter thread with some information on this](https://twitter.com/_Taurean/status/847497089189724164)